# Has CrossValidated (stats.stackexchange.com) gone offline?

Tags: support, offline

Not sure where to ask this so am posting it here.  (Apologies if it's not the right place.)

Does anyone know whether [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) is having server difficulties?  Half dozen of the other stack-exchange sites seem to be working but, but I've not been able to connect to CrossValidated for several hours now.

Many thanks for any info.

Comment: Works fine for me, probably something on your end blocking stuff.

Comment: .... and me....

Comment: I can't get onto http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ at the moment through the Google DNS (but I can from my phone that uses a different DNS).

Comment: Hm, strange.  But thanks for the feedback.  I'll have a play.

Comment: Let me know if you think I should now delete this post as it has served its purpose and probably doesn't offer any value worth preserving...

Comment: @AssadEbrahim Nah, keep it here. It's a good signpost for others who might have seen the same thing.